# "Not connected" message when any command is entered after FTP login

Tags: ftp

I am trying to use FTP from command prompt.So when I enter

```
c:\> ftp www.test.com
```

it waits for a while and changes to `ftp>`.

So I thought that the connection was successful even though it did not ask me for a username and password.

Now when I enter any command in this like `ls` or `dir` it gives a message saying "Not Connected".

I am not sure why it is saying that, is it that even if the connection fails the command prompt changes to `ftp>`?

Comment: Try issuing the "user" command to solicit the username/password prompts.

Comment: same response "Not connected" when I use the "user" command also....

Comment: How about the "open" command?

Comment: I used "open test.com" since the default value of port is 21 I never mentioned it in the command and I still get the same response as "Not Connected"

Comment: Are you sure the server has an FTP daemon running? Are you able to connect to other FTP servers with your ftp client?

Comment: I am new to using the FTP client...I have tried connecting to one ftp site which i found " ftp ftp.microsoft.com " and this was working fine. So is that the problem with the server that I was trying to connect before?

Comment: Most likely, yes. There is nothing more I can really do for you anymore, work with someone that actually manages that server.

Comment: thanks for your help...would try doing that..

Answer (score 2):

In the /etc/vsftpd.conf file uncomment  the following:

- local_enable=YES
- write_enable=YES
- anon_upload_enable=YES

Restart the FTP Service using the command:
 - sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart

Answer (score 2):

You probably should be using SFTP and not FTP. try

`sftp <user>@<host> <port>`

Answer (score 0):

It means there is a connection issue between you and the ftp server you're trying to communicate with.

1. Check to make sure your firewall/their firewall isn't blocking ftp.  Assuming ping is enabled trying to ping the ip address of the ftp server is a generally decent way to see if you can reach it.  You can also try telnet  21
2. Use Filezilla or some other ftp client (besides command line) to check to see if you can connect.